# How can I verify that Eclipse is using NDK?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk

I've followed the NDK tutorials and I'm still a bit confused. When I downloaded the android SDK, I had to tell the Eclipse IDE exactly where the SDK is located on disc. Cool. It worked, I'm happy.

The NDK instructions however don't tell you that. All they tell you is that you download the NDK and simply unzip it. It's just magically supposed to work.

I've followed the tutorial [HERE](http://mindtherobot.com/blog/452/android-beginners-ndk-setup-step-by-step/).

The code is not working.

So how can I verify that Eclipse even knows I've downloaded the NDK?

Also, I am running this from OSX, so I am not using Cygwin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you build your program you use:

```
cd <project>
<ndk>/ndk-build
```

where `<ndk>` is the path of the directory. thats it.